Number sequence puzzle: 14, 32, 69, 05,?
I made this puzzle on my own, feel free to solve it. Sequence is as follows: 14, 32, 69, 05, ?

Seems like the answer is

 50

Reason

 First of all imagine a loop which contains all the digits from 0-9 in numerical order… Also consider that the number needs to be two digits. Forgetting about the commas for a second, if you look at every odd digit, it is going +2,+3,+4 (the sequence loops back to zero here). These are going +1,+1 (or you can say you add the number of the term +1 leading to a ‘stronger pattern’) so we need 4+1 a leading to a +5 and this leads to 0+5=5!


 A similar logic applies to the even digits but it is instead -2,-3,-4,-5 instead each time leading to 5-5=0!

Here is a diagram making things clearer:

 

